# Running my program from PyDev with one click?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am developing using the PyDev plugin in Eclipse. My program uses several classes in several files. I usually run the program using the green "play" icon or using Control+F11. The only problem is that it will run the file, which is currently in "focus". Usually this is not the one containing the starting point of my application. As I run my program something like 200 times a day, this means that I need 200 extra click on the mouse and often forget about this.

Is there any way of setting the default file to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change the launching to rerun the last launched, so Ctrl+F11 will launch the last one -- and use F9 to launch the one with focus -- See instructions and details at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html

Answer (score 1):

For me, the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+F9.  I don't think I've changed any keybindings, so its strange that it would be different from the official documentation.

Go to Run->Run History, and select the run that is your 'main' run.  Now you should be able to use Ctrl-Shift+F9 from any other file to rerun your main.  If it isn't Ctrl+Shift+F9 for you,  look on the console window that should be at the bottom of your screen showing the stdout after every run.  There is an icon on the top of it that has the green start arrow with a yellow arrow underneath it pointing to the right.  That is the command to relaunch with the same configuration.  If you hover over that, it should tell you the keyboard shortcut you need.