# Ctrl-F11 runs current file. How do I run the "main" file?

Tags: pydev

I have several python files in my workspace. One is the file containing the main function. I.e main.py contains:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    DoImportantStuff()
```

The other files are classes that are used by the DoImportantStuff() function. One class per file. What's the suggested way to run the main file when I'm editing the other classes? Ctrl-F11 only runs the currently open file and since I'm often editing the other classes that don't have a main function nothing will happen. If I switch over to the main file I can run the program. But do I really have to switch to the main file first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339531/running-my-program-from-pydev-with-one-click), in a nutshell you should override `ctrl+F11` behavior

Comment: Thanks. Changing the "Launch Operation" in the eclipse settings fixed the issue.